# How to order standard SQS event message inside lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm working on an use case where I'm using standard SQS queue and that has been configured as a trigger to a S3 bucket(Put operation). So when ever there will be a new file inserted to the S3 bucket, that event message will be available in the SQS queue. And once I have any message in the queue I'm triggering a lambda function with the same event. So the design goes something like **S3 -> SQS -> Lambda**

But in a standard queue there is no guarantee of the order of the events and that I want to handle inside the lambda function. How can I ensure proper ordering inside lambda?

Comment: Hi. Could you explain (a little bit) why ordering is important in this case, please? The options you have really depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: For example - The S3 buckets is responsible for holding a customers order request in json formatted file, So if someone selected a t-shirt of size M and later he/she modified the size to L, finally your order should process L. If in case the ordering was missed, lambda will process size L first and then M. That's why we need ordering. I'm not sure if it makes sense but I think it's a good UC to consider @AdamBenson

Comment: Right - that makes sense, thanks. So, I guess that leads to the question is there a time stamp on the files that would allow for ordering? Also, does it have to go through SQS? S3 can trigger a lambda. In which case your lamdba could use redis as a mutex to synchronize access, then sort the files, process them in the right order, then delete. Would that work? Does SQS *have* to be in the picture?

Comment: Yes SQS has to be there according to our design. And yes the s3 event which the lambda function gets that has ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp and SentTimestamp which I thought can be used. But not sure how. @AdamBenson

Comment: "according to our design" - that's what I'm questioning :-) If the system is entirely in your control why not just have the lambda trigger when a file arrives in the bucket? Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html. The files will have a creation timestamp - see "Last-Modified" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html which should give enough resolution to order by.

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana Please mention if you have got the solution to this , i was also wondering how ordering can be achieved in lambda while using standard SQS